# Int object is not subscriptable error even though proper conversions have been made?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to create a program that is sort of an "expander". If you were to give it a number like 1234, it should return "1000 + 200 + 30 + 4". However, I keep getting an int object is not subscript able error even thought I made proper conversions.

I have tried having new_str = num[int(i)] ... but that still doesn't work.

```
def expanded_form(num):
    count = len(str(num))-1
    new_str = ""
    for i in range(0,len(str(num))):
        new_str += num[i] * 10**count + " + "
        count -= 1
    return new_str
print(expanded_form(1234))
```

Comment: If `num` is an int, it doesn't matter what `i` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is telling you that you cannot subscript an integer. Here: `num[i]`. `num` is an integer. You should cast it again to a string.
This said, to do what you want you need to recast the digit `num[i]` to an int in order to do the math.

```
def expanded_form(num):
    count = len(str(num))-1
    new_str = []
    for i in range(0,len(str(num))):
        new_str.append(int(str(num)[i]) * 10**count)
        count -= 1
    return ' + '.join(map(str, new_str))

print(expanded_form(1234))
```

Note that I made `new_str` a list and use `join` to build the string with the sum, to get rid of the extra `'+'` at the end. I also needed `map` to convert back all the integers to string otherwise `join` does not work.

Comment: Very nice solution. I had to add some things to meet the specifications of the problem such as getting rid of extra zeroes in some test cases where I had to remove zero. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is inside the for loop, you're writing num[i], that's what's giving you the error since num is an int and you can't really access an index of an int.

You're trying to get the number on that index and multiply it by 10 ** count. To do that should try this

```
new_str += str(int(str(num)[i]) * 10 ** count) + ' + '
```

You first have to turn num into a string to get the number on that position, but it returns it as a string, so you have to parse it back to int in order to multiply it with 10 ** count, and then you have to turn it into a string again in order to concatenate it with ' + '.

If you want to avoid parsing it so many times try doing this inside the for loop

```
new_str = str(num)[i] + '0' * count + ' + '
```

Instead of mutiplying it by a power of 10 you can use the fact that count is the number of zeros that should follow str(num)[i]

Comment: Incredible answer. I implemented both of the solutions listed and it was quite nice. Thank you for your help!